# Ambiguity about Angular component decorator behavior describes as in Angular documentation

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and currently i have gone through some examples which is given by angular.io site. But in the [component decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) explaination with in the documentation, it states that

> Angular components are a subset of directives, always associated with
>   a template. Unlike other directives, **only one component can be
>   instantiated per an element in a template**.

What they actually mean by **only one component can be instantiated per an element in a template.**

Can any one explain me this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually it means that within the angular ecosystem, Only one component will instantiated per an element (selector) within a template. Check following example.

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div style="text-align:center">
          Welcome to {{ title }}!
    </div> `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Test App';
}
```

try to use two selector tags within the index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular App</title>
  <base href="/">    
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

As a result, You will be see **only one** `Welcome to the Test App` **rendered in browser**. There can only ever be one component per html element

Comment: Thank you @Aravinda, I really appreciate your contribution towards me.

Answer (score 1):

**only one component can be instantiated per an element in a template.**

`AppComponent` can be instantiated to the element(`<my-app>`) in the DOM

- [There are many ways to reuse it(module, routing...)](https://www.google.com/search?q=reuse+componet+angular&oq=reuse+componet+angular+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5464j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[online example](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Chunbin, I really appreciate your contribution towards me.